# MySQL Connector C/C++ 8.0.13 - No UNICODE/UTF8 support?

Tags: c++, mysql, unicode

It seems like I'm at "risk" of being blocked from asking questions for some reason, but this is a question that I must ask.

Using MySQL connector C++, made my own little wrapper to accommodate my projects, everything OK.

However I cannot use UNICODE. There is literally no support for this, and we are in 2019.

**resultset.h**

```
  virtual SQLString getString(uint32_t columnIndex)  const = 0;
  virtual SQLString getString(const sql::SQLString& columnLabel) const = 0;
```

**sqlstring.h**

```
SQLString(const SQLString & other) : realStr(other.realStr) {}

SQLString(const std::string & other) : realStr(other) {}

SQLString(const char other[]) : realStr(other) {}

SQLString(const char * s, size_t n) : realStr(s, n) {}
```

So this question actually expands to more:

- Why is there no support for unicode ?
- Is there already support for it, am I just blind ?
- What can be done to have unicode support ?

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some answers as to why and where. More than sure that many people are looking for this and there is no conclusive answer or solution, again in 2019.

Many Thanks

Comment: The default for MySQL 8,0 is utf8mb4 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) and it has support for all four panes of the UNICODE character set

Comment: You cannot extract and print or use UNICODE data, specially with their function using "std::string". So, perhaps and example ?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Visual Studio... but what does this have to do with this ?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?  I'm using VS 2017 and having difficulties using MySQL Connector C++ 8.0.  I'm curious if anybody got the two working together and how.  I get errors when I build the connector.  I posted to the MySQL forum and still no response back or posted.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am using 2015, 2017 they all work ok. However the 8.0 I did not compile, just used the .lib and header files. If you are having issues it's clear... Seems like Oracle cannot do anything properly.

Comment: Search for `C++   UTF8`.  (Not Unicode)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this, partially. No UNICODE support however, but you can retrieve and print UTF-8 strings.

This is related to my other question ([Legacy MySQL Connector C++ using sql::ConnectOptionsMap exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996316/legacy-mysql-connector-c-using-sqlconnectoptionsmap-exception/53999638#53999638)) because in order to get UTF-8 strings back from MySQL, you need to use the following:

```
sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;

connection_properties["OPT_CHARSET_NAME"] = "utf8";
connection_properties["OPT_SET_CHARSET_NAME"] = "utf8";
```

And in order to use these options, you need to use the static version of MySQL Connector (mysqlcppconn-static.lib) from their website.

**Note:**

Doing this, will not work so don't waste your time:

```
Connection->setClientOption("OPT_CHARSET_NAME", "utf8");
Connection->setClientOption("OPT_SET_CHARSET_NAME", "utf8");
```

Such options need to be specified when you connect to MySQL.

I really hope my efforts will help someone in the near future.