# Legacy MySQL Connector C++ using sql::ConnectOptionsMap exception

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

It's been 2 days already that I am trying to understand why is this happening, however I do not have enough debugging skills to understand why is this occurring.

I need to use the *sql::ConnectOptionsMap* so I can pass my desired connection options such as charset, etc.

A simple example taken:

```
sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;

connection_properties["hostName"] = sql::SQLString("localhost");
connection_properties["userName"] = sql::SQLString("username");
connection_properties["password"] = sql::SQLString("password");
connection_properties["CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS"] = (true);

sql::Driver * driver = get_driver_instance();
std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect(connection_properties));
```

Compiled with VS 2017, under debug:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFECC811D0 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

After creating some "mini dumps", I can see the code is crashing here:

```
    _NODISCARD static _CONSTEXPR17 int compare(_In_reads_(_Count) const char * const _First1,
        _In_reads_(_Count) const char * const _First2, const size_t _Count) noexcept // strengthened
        {   // compare [_First1, _First1 + _Count) with [_First2, ...)
#if _HAS_CXX17
        return (__builtin_memcmp(_First1, _First2, _Count));
#else /* _HAS_CXX17 */
        return (_CSTD memcmp(_First1, _First2, _Count)); <-- HERE
#endif /* _HAS_CXX17 */
        }
```

Has anyone encountered this before ? I have searched a lot, and could not find anyone having this issue until now.

I really cannot understand why this is happening, since there is nothing custom, just an example from the docs...

Please advise.

Comment: Wild guess: Ar you missing a _port_ or _database_ parameter specification?

Comment: CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS is an enumerated integer and you are using it as text.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I get you... however that was the first thing I tried, multiple combinations and the result is the same. You can try it out, simple new windows console app, mysqlconnector library and this code.

Comment: @peakpeak I'm really not sure I understand what you mean, however I tested without this option as well, and the result is the same...

Comment: @NorbertBoros Sorry, no MySQL or MySQL connector on this machine. First thing I'd try to do is to inspect the stack traces more thoroughly.

Comment: Can someone please explain to Norbert that he cannot use CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS  as a literal (string) as it is an integer.

Comment: @peakpeak Please document yourself before making such conclusions... and furthermore, read what I replied to you, the result is the same even if you COMMENT THAT OPTION. And again, document ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html

Comment: Well, using an enum integer as a literal string proves you have documented yourself. I'm trying to help and you get upset?

Comment: Yes because that is not the issue here, even if you comment that (don't use that option) the result is the same. We are deviating from the actual issue... I looked into the source and the hostname, username and passwords are mandatory only. So that's not the issue either. It has something to do with std::map, not sure what.

Comment: That is not the issue here now, ok. But the start of this thread had an error, that's what my focus was on. Let's find the solution then.
Please post your revised code

Comment: @peakpeak Yes, let's do that. Download: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/ Windows (x86, 64-bit), ZIP Archive, spin up a new Windows Console app, and try that code out. You will see... Or maybe I am doing something wrong, and loosing my mind.

Comment: I cannot login to that page.

Comment: @peakpeak You don't need to, here's direct link: https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C++/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13-winx64.zip

Comment: @peakpeak I just found this, and tested, and this error is gone. http://www.codeblogbt.com/archives/471616 HOWEVER, this is not the solution... to add code manually into the mysql connector...

Answer (score 1):

I found finally the answer to this problem, which is not documented anywhere. You can use "sql::ConnectOptionsMap connection_properties;" **ONLY if you are statically linking** the library. (mysqlcppconn-static.lib)

How I found this out ? Following this amazing information from: http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-yltwwlte-pd.html

**Quote:**

> The strings used in the interface are all SQLString. Although it is a
>   further wrapper of std::string, it is impossible to pass a std::string
>   object as a parameter. Because it is a way of dynamic linking, the
>   memory management in the DLL has no connection with the EXE. Passing
>   the object in the past will cause an exception: bad_alloc

I did however test the code from the article and added into the mysql_connection.cpp, and the error is gone but it will still not work.

**My caveat:**

I was building my own "Debug" version of the mysql-connector-cpp-master, and for some reason the compilation is not "as expected". For example in my compilation the "mysqlcppconn-static.lib" cannot be compiled as Debug, only "RelWithDebInfo" and is only 10 MB, whilst the "official" one is 64 MB.

**Conclusion:**

You must statically link the Release version (mysqlcppconn-static.lib) from the MySQL website in order to use "sql::ConnectOptionsMap". I really hope they will wake up and make a proper lib for people and documentation as well.

If I can find a way to build this in Debug mode, I shall post an update.